# How to put to .xib file cuctom class which inherits UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I have copied class from net which inherits UIImageView. How to put that class on .xib file ?

Comment: what do you mean by putting it in an xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UIImageView to your .xib, then select it, click on the identity inspector, and change the class from UIImageView to your new class.

Thus, when you first select the image view, you'll see:

[image: UIImageView identity inspector]

Change it to whatever subclass you have, e.g. in my example, UIImageViewSubclass:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to project Navigator Edit-> Navigator->show project navigator or(cmd+1) select File Owner[image: AS shown here].

In 3rd Tab in Navigation Editor you can find Custom class Type your class name there and your class will be linked with this xib file. Do as shown in figure

[image: Do as shown in figure]

Comment: If it's a UIImageView subclass, he presumably wants to not change the view controller class, but rather change a for a UIImageView that he adds to his view.